# Correlation coefficients for sparse matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, correlation

Does anyone know how to compute a correlation matrix from a very large sparse matrix in python?  Basically, I am looking for something like `numpy.corrcoef` that will work on a scipy sparse matrix.

Answer (score 14):

You can compute the correlation coefficients fairly straightforwardly from the covariance matrix like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def sparse_corrcoef(A, B=None):

    if B is not None:
        A = sparse.vstack((A, B), format='csr')

    A = A.astype(np.float64)
    n = A.shape[1]

    # Compute the covariance matrix
    rowsum = A.sum(1)
    centering = rowsum.dot(rowsum.T.conjugate()) / n
    C = (A.dot(A.T.conjugate()) - centering) / (n - 1)

    # The correlation coefficients are given by
    # C_{i,j} / sqrt(C_{i} * C_{j})
    d = np.diag(C)
    coeffs = C / np.sqrt(np.outer(d, d))

    return coeffs
```

Check that it works OK:

```
# some smallish sparse random matrices
a = sparse.rand(100, 100000, density=0.1, format='csr')
b = sparse.rand(100, 100000, density=0.1, format='csr')

coeffs1 = sparse_corrcoef(a, b)
coeffs2 = np.corrcoef(a.todense(), b.todense())

print(np.allclose(coeffs1, coeffs2))
# True
```

### Be warned:

The amount of memory required for computing the covariance matrix `C` will  be heavily dependent on the sparsity structure of `A` (and `B`, if given). For example, if `A` is an `(m, n)` matrix containing just a *single* column of non-zero values then `C` will be an `(n, n)` matrix containing *all* non-zero values. If `n` is large then this could be very bad news in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: Very helpful thanks... I've modifed the numpy corrcoef method for memory savings. I suggest the following:   use these type of operations, A -= A or A /= A. Convert to np.float32, BLAS has functions for both 64 and 32 bit floats. Drop the conjugate unless you need it. One reason the memory is so bad is likely b/c the dot product routine expects square-ish matrices and actually pads out with zeros for optimization. Former boss was very good with computational C.

Comment: @wbg The issue I was pointing out is that, depending on its sparsity structure, even a very sparse array can still have a very dense covariance matrix. This is not really a problem with the implementation details, but is rather a fundamental issue when computing the covariance matrices of sparse arrays. There are a few work-arounds, for example by computing a truncated version of the covariance matrix by imposing a penalty on its L1 norm (e.g. [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7907)).

Comment: Thx for rhe tip abt using a penalty. I thini this topic is rich for study. Cheers.

Comment: Unless the data are already centred, `A = A - A.mean(1)` will destroy any sparsity. You may as well just convert to dense first!

Comment: @joeln Good point - I've updated my answer to avoid doing this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused: what are A and B in this function?

Answer (score 12):

You do not need to introduce a large dense matrix. Just keep it sparse using Numpy:

```
import numpy as np    
def sparse_corr(A):
    N = A.shape[0]
    C=((A.T*A -(sum(A).T*sum(A)/N))/(N-1)).todense()
    V=np.sqrt(np.mat(np.diag(C)).T*np.mat(np.diag(C)))
    COR = np.divide(C,V+1e-119)
    return COR
```

## Testing the performance:

```
A = sparse.rand(1000000, 100, density=0.1, format='csr')
sparse_corr(A)
```

Comment: This is a good response. It produces a dense covariance matrix, but never changes the sparsity pattern of the input matrix.

Comment: This is an excellent response for the reason @joeln mentioned. I needed the covariance matrix for a massive dataset so that I could look for multicollinearity among the features using eigendecomposition. Well done.

Comment: @Alt `sum(A)` sums up all elements, no? Isn't it supposed to be row sums?

Comment: @gkcn, on sparse (CSR) matrices, "sum" just adds the rows. I'll update my answer to make it easier to use

Comment: @Alt Are you sure? `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([[1,2], [3,4]]).sum()` gives 10. Edit: Oh now I see, not x.sum() but sum(x), please ignore :)

Comment: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3383,3142) (3142,3383)

Answer (score 1):

I present an answer for a scipy sparse matrix which runs in parallel.  Rather than returning a giant correlation matrix, this returns a feature mask of fields to keep after checking all fields for both positive and negative Pearson correlations.

**I also try to minimize calculations using the following strategy:**

- Process each column
- Start at the current column + 1 and calculate correlations moving to the right.
- For any abs(correlation) >= threshold, mark the current column for removal and calculate no further correlations.
- Perform these steps for each column in the dataset except the last.

This might be sped up further by keeping a global list of columns marked for removal and skipping further correlation calculations for such columns, since columns will execute out of order.  However, I do not know enough about race conditions in python to implement this tonight.

Returning a column mask will obviously allow the code to handle much larger datasets than returning the entire correlation matrix.

**Check each column using this function:**

```
def get_corr_row(idx_num, sp_mat, thresh):
    # slice the column at idx_num
    cols = sp_mat.shape[1]
    x = sp_mat[:,idx_num].toarray().ravel()
    start = idx_num + 1
    
    # Now slice each column to the right of idx_num   
    for i in range(start, cols):
        y = sp_mat[:,i].toarray().ravel()
        # Check the pearson correlation
        corr, pVal = pearsonr(x,y)
        # Pearson ranges from -1 to 1.
        # We check both positive and negative correlations >= thresh using abs(corr)
        if abs(corr) >= thresh:
            # stop checking after finding the 1st correlation > thresh   
            return False
            # Mark column at idx_num for removal in the mask  
    return True
```

**Run the column level correlation checks in parallel:**

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed  
import multiprocessing


def Get_Corr_Mask(sp_mat, thresh, n_jobs=-1):
    
    # we must make sure the matrix is in csc format 
    # before we start doing all these column slices!  
    sp_mat = sp_mat.tocsc()
    cols = sp_mat.shape[1]
    
    if n_jobs == -1:
        # Process the work on all available CPU cores
        num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    else:
        # Process the work on the specified number of CPU cores
        num_cores = n_jobs

    # Return a mask of all columns to keep by calling get_corr_row() 
    # once for each column in the matrix     
    return Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores, verbose=5)(delayed(get_corr_row)(i, sp_mat, thresh)for i in range(cols))
```

**General Usage:**

```
#Get the mask using your sparse matrix and threshold.
corr_mask = Get_Corr_Mask(X_t_fpr, 0.95) 

# Remove features that are >= 95% correlated
X_t_fpr_corr = X_t_fpr[:,corr_mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [Alt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38727681/3490833) didn't work out for me. The values given to the `np.sqrt` function where mostly negative, so the resulting covariance values were nan.

I wasn't able to use [ali_m's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235925/3490833) as well, because my matrix was too large that I couldn't fit the `centering = rowsum.dot(rowsum.T.conjugate()) / n` matrix in my memory (My matrix's dimensions are: 3.5*10^6 x 33)

Instead, I used [scikit-learn's `StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) to compute the standard sparse matrix and then used a multiplication to obtain the correlation matrix.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

def compute_sparse_correlation_matrix(A):
    scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False)
    scaled_A = scaler.fit_transform(A)  # Assuming A is a CSR or CSC matrix
    corr_matrix = (1/scaled_A.shape[0]) * (scaled_A.T @ scaled_A)
    return corr_matrix
```

I believe that this approach is faster and more robust than the other mentioned approaches. Moreover, it also preserves the sparsity pattern of the input matrix.

Comment: Unless you are complex numbers (which is not the case here), in V=np.sqrt(np.mat(np.diag(C)).T*np.mat(np.diag(C))), np.mat(np.diag(C)).T*np.mat(np.diag(C)) will only have non-negative entries. Because it multiplies a diagonal matrix by itself. so each entry in np.diag(C) will be squared. 
I would debug my code, there is a chance that something else is going wrong in your code.