# Calculating a pairwise correlation matrix of very large vectors

Tags: python, pandas

What would be the most python-esque way for calculating a correlation matrix of extremely large vectors?

For example, I have 23 vectors, each with length 40,000 (!). [pandas.Dataframe.corr()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) method runs out of RAM for this.

Comment: How sparse are they? Could you benefit from an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231268/correlation-coefficients-for-sparse-matrix-in-python)? If you can't benefit from a sparse representation, and it's Pearson method you need, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437513/finding-the-correlation-matrix)?

Comment: You probably have it transposed, this should be an instantaneous calculation.  Assuming you want a 23x23 correlation matrix, right?  In pandas, you should have 40,000 rows and 23 columns.  Numpy wants it the other way (23 rows, 40,000 columns).  Do it in numpy, should be about 30x faster:  `np.corrcoef(arr)`.

Comment: @JohnE in Pandas, I had 23 rows and 40,000 columns (should it have been the other way around? does it matter?) but you are right, np.corrcoef did this instantaneously! Thank you! Why is pandas.Dataframe.corr() so slow?

Comment: pandas just has more overhead than numpy.  But it should still be quite fast here if you transpose first.  Just not as fast as numpy but either way takes less than a second on my laptop

Comment: Consider using [dask](http://dask.pydata.org)